# php multilanguage website error issue

Tags: php

i am new to php and i was trying to create a simple multilanguage web site with php. am mentioned below my total code, and i am having the total four files, index.php, setlocal.php, and one folder locale within that en.php, fn.php files. am having the folder structure like this..

```
----  
index.php  
setlocal.php  

locale  
 en.php  
 fn.php
```

the file codes are..

**index.php**

```
<?php  
include_once "setlocal.php";  
?>  

<!doctype html>  
<head>  
<title><?php echo $GLOBALS['l']['title1']; ?></title>  
</head>  
<body>  

<ul class="header-nav pull-right">  
<li><a href="index.php?lang=en">English</a></li>  
<li><a href="index.php?lang=fn">French</a></li>  
</ul>  

<p><?php echo $GLOBALS['l']['homdes1']; ?></p>  

</body>  
</html>
```

**setlocal.php**

```
<?php  

($language = @$_GET['lang']) or $language = 'en';  

$allowed = array('en', 'te');  

if(!in_array($language, $allowed)) {  
$language = 'en';  
}  

include "locale/{$language}.php";  

$GLOBALS['l'] = '$local';  

?>
```

**locale

     |

    en.php**

```
<?php  

$local = array (  
'title1' => 'sample english content',  
'homdes1' => 'sample english contentsample english contentsample english content');  

?>
```

**fn.php**

```
<?php  

$local = array (  
'title1' => 'sample french content',  
'homdes1' => 'sample french contentsample french contentsample french contentsample       french contentsample french content');  

?>
```

when am running the code it was showing the error like this below, kindly help me to solve  this issue, thank you.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'homdes1' in  D:\madhu_new\korimerla\htdocs\korimerla\php\index.php on line 15  
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the quotes around `$local` from this line in file `setlocal.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['l'] = '$local';
```

so that it reads:

```
$GLOBALS['l'] = $local;
```

This will give you:

```
// you can use var_dmp() this to see what you have in $GLOBALS['l']
var_dump($GLOBALS['l']);

array(2) {
  ["title1"]=>
  string(22) "sample english content"
  ["homdes1"]=>
  string(66) "sample english contentsample english contentsample english content"
}
```

This can then be accessed using the array syntax:

```
echo $GLOBALS['l']['homdes1'];

// gives:    
sample english contentsample english contentsample english content
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your setlocal.php to this:

```
<?php  

//Check if $_GET['lang'] is set, if not default to 'en'
$language = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';

$allowed = array('en', 'te');  

if(!in_array($language, $allowed)) {  
  $language = 'en';  
}  

include "locale/$language.php";  

//without single quotes. PHP will expand (convert) variable names inside double quotes to the value, but within single vars are printed as is.
$GLOBALS['l'] = $local; 

?>
```